# UIrefreshcontrol doesn't reload new items with pagination

Tags: swift, cocoapods, pull-to-refresh

I have imported a cocoa pod namely PaginatedTableView and it has built in UIRefreshControl and Pagination features. When I pull up the page, app crashes because of index out of range error which I think is happening because of Refreshcontrol.

I have tried to find where is the error but it just seems fine.

```
lazy var refreshControltableView: UIRefreshControl = {
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handleRefreshtableView(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
    return refreshControl
}()

extension PaginatedTableView {

public func loadData(refresh: Bool = false) {
    load(refresh: refresh)
}

@objc fileprivate func handleRefreshtableView(_ refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
    load(refresh: true)
}

// All loading logic goes here i.e. showing/hiding of loaders and pagination
private func load(refresh: Bool = false) {

    // reset page number if refresh
    if refresh {
        currentPage = firstPage
        hasMoreData = true
    }

    // return if already loading or dont have any more data
    if !hasMoreData || isLoading {
        return }

    // start loading
    isLoading = true

    paginatedDelegate?.loadMore(currentPage, pageSize, onSuccess: { hasMore in
        self.hasMoreData = hasMore
        self.currentPage += 1
        self.isLoading = false
        self.refreshControltableView.endRefreshing()
        if self.customReloadDataBlock != nil {
            self.customReloadDataBlock?()
        } else {
            self.reloadData()
        }
    }, onError: { _ in
        self.refreshControltableView.endRefreshing()
        self.isLoading = false
    })
}

// Scroll to end detector
public func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let height = scrollView.frame.size.height
    let contentYoffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let distanceFromBottom = scrollView.contentSize.height - contentYoffset
    if distanceFromBottom < height {
        load()
    }
}
}



func loadMore(_ pageNumber: Int, _ pageSize: Int, onSuccess: ((Bool) -> Void)?, onError: ((Error) -> Void)?) {
    // Call your api here
    if pageNumber < pages - 1 {
        onSuccess?(true)
        print("success")
    }
    else {
        onSuccess?(false)
    }
    // Send true in onSuccess in case new data exists, sending false will disable pagination

    // If page number is first, reset the list
    if pageNumber == 0 {
        cleaner()
        }
    myApi(pageNumber)
    // else append the data to list
    // If Api responds with error


    // Else end success with flag true if more data available
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! myTableCell
    cell.myLabel.text = self.labelArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.myImage.image = self.imageArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.myDateLabel.text = self.labelDateArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

loadMore function is in delegate class. myApi function finds the data and appends it to the list. 
This is the Pod code which I think is related with my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know what line is causing the error? Try setting an exception breakpoint in Xcode. Then you will know what is causing the out of range error.

Comment: I added it but nothing happened. Actually my error is in cellforrowat function because of a lists index out of range. I think when I refresh the tableview I delete the list but then when I scrolldown It just doesn't reload.

Comment: Please share your code in `cellForRowAt`

Comment: I have just added it.

Comment: Maybe one of your three data arrays is out of sync, causing the error. Instead of using three different arrays, I would use an array of structs with three properties: label, image and labelDate.

Comment: I don't think that this is the case because when I switch the lines of code for arrays it always breaks in the first line.

Comment: Can you share the code where you set up those three arrays? Somehow they are causing that error.